# Does "on your opponent's 3rd turn" mean after 3 turns?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

The text of "Swords of Revealing Light" reads

> After this card's activation, it remains on the battlefield, but destroy it during the End Phase of your opponent's 3rd turn.

In previous versions it has specified

> This card remains on the field for 3 of your opponent's turns.

So it has been changed from that, presumably for a reason.

In my mind, my opponent's 3rd turn is not the same as 3 (of my opponent's) turns after I activate the card and would imply the card is not destroyed if I activate it on or after my opponent's 4th turn.

How should the text be interpreted?

Comment: Re "*presumably for a reason*", I don't know the game, but the original effect doesn't say what to do after the time has elapsed, and it's not exactly clear when the time elapsed. I don't think they meant to change 3rd turn from now (when the effect came into existence) to 3rd turn from the start of the game. It should have specified which, but the one that didn't introduce a massive change is probably the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function of the card hasn't changed, but the wording change isn't great.

The new wording creates ambiguity in what "third turn" means, but only one interpretation makes logical sense for gameplay, even if it's the less likely meaning under the rules of English. It looks like they wanted to be more specific on when it's destroyed (the end of your opponent's turn rather than the start of yours) which was a bit unclear in the original wording. There's definitely a better middle ground between the two card wordings, one that specifies 3 turns from when it was played perhaps something like this:

> After this card's activation, it remains on the battlefield for 3 of your opponent's turns, destroy it during the End Phase of your that turn.

There's no real way to know what made Konami change the wording to this unless the company tells the players, anything else is really just speculation.

Answer (score -1):

It would mean after your opponent finish 3 turns. That's why it's such a good card.